# ajax call failed after building APK using PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, cordova

i am trying to run my app after using phonegap but failing to pass the AJAX code section
it work perferctly on Ripple emulator but after installing it on my device (android 5.0) the ajax call just failed (Getting the ErrMSG).
Thanks
this is the code i am using:

```
 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "LogIn.aspx/UserCheck",
                                data: "{'UserName':'" + UserName + "','Password':'" + Password + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json",                       
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (msg) {
                                if (msg.d == true) {
                                    window.location.href = "Default.aspx";
                                }
                                else
                                    alert("please insert correct username and password");
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Ajax Call Failed');
                        }
                        });
```

Comment: You have to use the absolute url, something like http://yourserver.com/LogIn.aspx/UserCheck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ajax call is calling on your local web server. Since you are not running now on your local web server you will need to adjust your ajax call to hit the full url. You have two places (at least in the code you have provided):

```
url: "LogIn.aspx/UserCheck"
```

and

```
window.location.href = "Default.aspx";
```

This last bit of code really needs to be a page or block of code in your app. This way if the phone is not connected to the Internet for whatever reason you still can give your users a valid error message.

Once this is done you will then need to [whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) your domain in your app.

Answer (score 0):

1. After deploy to phone, you have a Cross Domain call to your aspx.  so you also need to enable Cors.
2. Why do you redirect to default.aspx after login?  if you redirect from the original index.html, which is located in the phone to the default.aspx which is located in the IIS Server, you lost control of the phone application, all plugins will not work, just like your apps become a mobile browser.
3. btw, r u using vb or c# in the aspx?